# How to count individuals by age bracket?

Tags: searchkit

I wonder if it is possible in search kit to create a query that counts individuals by age bracket. A count by age is very straightforward but I don't know how to define age brackets like 0-10, 10-20, etc.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer to this is to use Data Segmentation which is a feature added in very recent releases.

The workflow is something along the lines of

- create a bunch of Data Segments (eg one for each age group)
- add these segments as values in the Search Kit

(i will ask my colleague to explain in a bit more detail)

Answer (score 7):

I was able to create the search, thanks to the input of petednz.

First, create a data segmentation for the age brackets, like so:

[image: Data segment for age brackets]

Next, you can use the data segment in the group by clause of the query, like so:
[image]

Comment: Good on you for doing the write up for others.

Comment: Coleman covers this here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Tt2Puupip0 about 12 minutes in.