# Group by Having criteria in searchkit results

Tags: searchkit

I'm trying to create one report showing groups of total sum quantities in ranges.

I'm sure there may be other, better ways to do this, perhaps with smartgroups but those solutions have also eluded me.

For example, I have a contribution report that uses "sum" of contributions for my donors. I'd like to be able, in one report, to have groupings of these in ranges (e.g. ignore under $100 then: $101 - $200, $200-300, $500+, etc.)

It seems using the Having filters (grouping after data is pulled) would be the best way to go about this. I have set up Or conditions to replicate the ranges based on the sums. But I can't seem to find a way to reference these groupings after the fact to rewrite the fields or reference the new groupings.

The ideal table would be something like:
Name        Donor Level  Total Donations
Donor1        $500+          $812
Donor2       $400-500        $438
Donor3       $400-500        $427
Donor4       $100-200        $117

Comment: Just sharing some of our experiences: Using "having filters" can have big performance issues, particularly if you have a larger databases and/or use several entity joins in the searchkit. So make sure you test properly before deploying on a productive system ^^

Comment: Did you try data segmentation in searhkit?
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/43198/321